# How Sum input fields values after save in cakephp?

Tags: forms, cakephp, input, sum

> Good afternoon, first of all a cordial greetings to all forum. I have
>   a problem and need help. Please would be so kind to help me with
>   information, text, illustrations, to perform mathematical operations
>   in cakephp, the problem is that I am still a newbie and I was a bit
>   complicated all this, to get a better idea this is my view

Form view:

http://www.subirimagenes.com/imagedata.php?url=http://s2.subirimagenes.com/otros/9234902vistaprevia.jpg

Example:

form:
    3 * 7.50  = 22.50
form:
    4 * 5.50  = 22
form:
    1 * 4.90  = 4.90
form:
    2 * 12.90 = 25.8

total:          72.50

> What I want to do is take the amounts written on the forms and then do
>   the calculation and place in the total field

DB view

http://www.subirimagenes.com/imagedata.php?url=http://s2.subirimagenes.com/otros/9234906db.jpg

----------view/add.ctp.........

```
<div class="ventas form">
   <?php echo $this->Form->create('Venta'); ?>
   <fieldset>
    <legend><?php echo __('PROCESO DE COMPRA'); ?></legend>
    <?php
    echo $this->Form->input('nombre');
    echo $this->Form->input('apellido');
    echo $this->Form->input('cedula');
    echo $this->Form->input('direccion');
    echo $this->Form->input('mail');
    echo $this->Form->input('telefono');
    echo $this->Form->input('tarjeta');
    echo $this->Form->input('numtarjeta');
    echo __('<legend>SELECCIONE SU PELICULA</legend>'); 
    echo $this->Form->input('cartelera_id',array('label' => 'Seleccione su pelicula'));
    echo $this->Form->input('cant_adulto', array('label' => 'Cantidad de boletos - Precio normal $ 7,50'));
    echo $this->Form->input('cant_niño', array('label' => 'Cantidad de boletos - Precio niños/ancianos $ 5,50'));
    echo $this->Form->input('cant_discapacitado', array('label' => 'Cantidad de boletos - Precio discapacitados $ 4,90'));

echo __('<legend>SELECCIONE SU COMBO</legend>'); 
    echo $this->Form->input('combo_id');
    echo $this->Form->input('numcombo', array('label' => 'Cantidad de combos - Precio discapacitados $ 12,90'));
    echo $this->Form->input('total');
    ?>
   </fieldset>

<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Guardar')); ?>

</div>
```

.......Controller.......

```
   class VentasController extends AppController {
/** * Components
 * * @var array
 */ public $components = array('Paginator');
/** * index method
 * * @return void
 */
    public function index() {
        $this->Venta->recursive = 0;
        $this->set('ventas', $this->Paginator->paginate());
    }/**
 * view method
 *
 * @throws NotFoundException
 * @param string $id
 * @return void
 */
    public function view($id = null) {
        if (!$this->Venta->exists($id)) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid venta'));
        }
        $options = array('conditions' => array('Venta.' . $this->Venta->primaryKey => $id));
        $this->set('venta', $this->Venta->find('first', $options));
    }
/**
 * add method *
 * @return void */
    public function add() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->Venta->create();
            if ($this->Venta->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('La venta se almacenó correctamente.'));
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('La venta no se almacenó correctamente. Por favor, Intente de nuevo.'));
            }
        }
        $carteleras = $this->Venta->Cartelera->find('list',array('fields'=>'pelicula'));
        $this->set(compact('carteleras'));
        $combos = $this->Venta->Combo->find('list',array('fields'=>'nombre'));
        $this->set(compact('combos'));
    }
/** * edit method
 * * @throws NotFoundException
 * @param string $id
 * @return void
 */ public function edit($id = null) {
        if (!$this->Venta->exists($id)) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid venta'));
        }
        if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))) {
            if ($this->Venta->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('La venta se almacenó correctamente.'));
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('La venta no se almacenó correctamente. Por favor, Intente de nuevo.'));
            }
        } else {
            $options = array('conditions' => array('Venta.' . $this->Venta->primaryKey => $id));
            $this->request->data = $this->Venta->find('first', $options);
        }
        $carteleras = $this->Venta->Cartelera->find('list');
        $this->set(compact('carteleras'));
        $combos = $this->Venta->Combo->find('list');
        $this->set(compact('combos'));
    }
/**
 * delete method *
 * @throws NotFoundException
 * @param string $id
 * @return void
 */ public function delete($id = null) {
        $this->Venta->id = $id;
        if (!$this->Venta->exists()) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid venta'));
        }
```

Thank you very much for your attention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function vent() {
   if ($this->request->is('post')) {
       $this->Venta->create();
       $this->request->data['Venta']['total'] = ($this->request->data['Venta']        
        ['cant_adulto'] * 7.5) + ($this->request->data['Venta']['cant_niño'] *  
        5.5) +  ($this->request->data['Venta']['cant_discapacitado'] * 4.9)+ 
        ($this->request->data['Venta']['numcombo'] * 12.9) ;
   if ($this->Venta->save($this->request->data)) {

   $this->Session->setFlash(__('La venta se almacenó correctamente.'));
   $inserted_id=$this->Venta->id;
   return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'view', $inserted_id));
   } else {
   $this->Session->setFlash(__('La venta no se almacenó correctamente. Por   
   favor, Intente de nuevo.'));
   }}
   $carteleras = $this->Venta->Cartelera-  
                 >find('list',array('fields'=>'pelicula'));
   $this->set(compact('carteleras'));
   $combos = $this->Venta->Combo->find('list',array('fields'=>'nombre'));
   $this->set(compact('combos'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [beforeSave()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html#beforesave) callback of the model. Do your calculation there and write to the field.

[Example taken from the book:](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html#beforesave)

```
public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
    if (!empty($this->data['Event']['begindate']) &&
        !empty($this->data['Event']['enddate'])
    ) {

        $this->data['Event']['begindate'] = $this->dateFormatBeforeSave(
            $this->data['Event']['begindate']
        );
        $this->data['Event']['enddate'] = $this->dateFormatBeforeSave(
            $this->data['Event']['enddate']
        );
    }
    return true;
}

public function dateFormatBeforeSave($dateString) {
    return date('Y-m-d', strtotime($dateString));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering this question.
Can you help me?, I try to beforesave () function, but do not understand the logic, I've been trying to do this for 4 days.

Comment: What is not understandable in the documentation and provided example? Just make your calculations and set the result to your total field and you're done. The example code shows exactly this just with changing a date.